# SharePoint Record center not showing all documents after content db restore

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database, records-center

I am moving a SharePoint 2013 content database from a SharePoint farm to another one using the SQL backup/restore way and mounted successfully the content database to the new web application via PowerShell (including the -AssignNewDatabaseId parameter)

When I open the record center site on the new farm some of the documents are shown but not all.

After doing some investigation I found that on the existing farm all the documents (in the [AllDocs] table) have the Dirty bit set to 0, while on the new farm the very same row has the dirty bit set to 1.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some long hours of troubleshooting and investigation of queries going to database (by using SQL profiler) 
To do this I god a document ID from the old farm, which I knew should be in the database, but was not showing in the new farm.
I noticed that the queries were going to another site (probably obsolete)  in the site collection.

Opening the allsites table in SQL Management studio I noticed that inside the database there was an identical (but older) version of the site and subsite structure. My previous farm was pointing to the right sites, but after restore to the new farm, somehow SharePoint had started referencing the old/obsolete sites inside the content DB.

The resolution was to delete the obsolete site, dismount the content database and mount again. And voila, the record center is showing the latest content again.

Hope this helps anyone facing similar/strange issues with SharePoint after restoring content DB to a new farm.